# iPod show memory and cpu

Tags: iphone

I need to create an app for my ipod 2G, where I show the cpu utilization and the memory usage instantly. How I can do this? I've searched a lot in web but I can't find anything about this.

Thanks for all the help and hints.

Best regards,
Hugo Silva

Comment: I don't know for sure so I'm just going to post this as a comment. This is something I highly doubt Apple allows developers access to through iOS. Might be possible if you are developing for jailbroken devices :)

Comment: The device is jailbroken... )

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean in like a label?  If not, you can use Instruments.